# How to get customer billing address in blCheckoutWorkflow in broadleaf?

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I would like to the get customer billing address details and would like to log them in an *activity class* in the `blCheckoutWorkflow`.

I have tried the following.

```
Order order=context.getOrder();
Customer c=order.getCustomer();
c.getCustomerPayments().get(0).getBillingAddress();
```

But here the size of the list returned by `getCustomerPayments()` is `0`. So I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Is there a way to get the billing address that is entered by the customer in the `/checkout`.

Kindly, reply me.

Answer (score 0):

`getCustomerPayments()` is designed to hold saved payment information for a particular Customer and is not really applicable to the current Order. This is used when a Customer wants to save payment information for checking out next time (the 'token' property on CustomerPaymentImpl is used to look up the PCI-sensitive data from the payment gateway).

If you are using Broadleaf 3.1.0-GA+ then you should do:

```
Order order = context.getOrder();
Address billingAddress = order.getOrderPayments().get(0).getBillingAddress();
```

If you are using Broadleaf 3.0.10-GA or below you should do:

```
Order order = context.getOrder();
Address billingAddress = order.getPaymentInfos().get(0).getAddress();
```

Comment: The variable `context` is of type `ProcessContext<CheckoutSeed>`, so I got a `ClassCastException`. Though I tried using `context.getSeedData()` to get the context object, I am getting `null` only.

Comment: By the way, there is also no method called `getOrderPayments()`, it is `getPayments()`